# Monitor ubuntu system metrics through grafana + telegraf

Tags: ubuntu, jmeter, influxdb, grafana

I have a system configured with Telegraf + InfluxDB + Grafana on one machine.

Now I need to collect server metrics for Ubuntu servers which is deployed in the cloud and need to plot in Grafana.

My question here is :

1. Can I collect the metrics through Telegraf itself ? if yes then do I need to install Telegraf in all the cloud servers to pull the metrics ?
2. Is there any other way to pull the metrics from AWS cloud servers and store it in the central Influxdb database ?
3. Is it possible to perform it through any other plugins available in Jmeter itself ?

Thanks In Advance for the valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you can and yes you need to install the [telegraf agent](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.12/introduction/getting-started/) on each server you want to monitor
2. There are other ways of collecting server performance data:

   - [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/), in this case you will need to install [PerfMon Server Agent](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent) onto all servers
   - [SSHMon Samples Collector](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-sshmon#sshmon-samples-collector-), you will not need to install any software onto servers, however you will need to have [SSH](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/protocol/) connectivity with all servers you want to monitor
3. I'm not aware of any existing plugins, however you can come up with your own implementation of the [AbstractBackendListenerClient](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/backend/AbstractBackendListenerClient.html) which will be sending server-side performance metrics to InfluxDB

Comment: Thanks much for the response Dmitri ..  

Also i would like to know more about monitoring & collecting metrics from Distributed servers.

* I would like to setup  one Server (with influxDb and telegraf ) which collects and stores all the other server metrics.
Here would like to know on configs to send the system metrics to the main server and config to receive the metrics through Telegraf.